# How can i disable the inner part of combo box in sap ui5?i.e to make it readonly(user shouldnt be allowed to type

Tags: combobox, sapui5

```
                tooltip="Choose Data type" items="{path:'/COLUMNMETADATADATATYPES'}"


                value="{formulaData>/CustomKeyDataTypeID}"  >


                <core:Item key="{path:'DATATYPEID'}" text="{path:'DATATYPEID'}"></core:Item>



            </ComboBox>
```

i have defined my combo box in xml view as shown above which i have to disable

Comment: add property enabled="false"

Answer (score 4):

Euh, a ComboBox is just that, a "combo" of a DropdownBox with an editable Textfield.

If you don't want users to type in data, you don't need the "combo", so why don't you simply use a DropdownBox instead?

Answer (score 3):

**There is no any methods to disable to user**
*Instead of "Combobox" you will go with the "Select" control*

Answer (score 3):

**tl.dr; Use sap.m.Select**

By using a `sap.m.Combobox` you cannot disable text input and selection at the same time by setting its editable property to `false`.

Instead you could use the following options:

- `sap.ui.commons.DropdownBox` - it would provide what you need, but it is in the commons namespace meaning that it is not mobile optimised. What is more, it is also deprecated in favor of ComboBox since version 1.38. It is also not a good idea to mix it with `sap.m` controls, see: [SAPUI5 deprecated themes and libraries](https://sapui5.netweaver.ondemand.com/#/topic/a87ca843bcee469f82a9072927a7dcdb.html)
- `sap.m.Select` - this is what you need. It only allows a selection from the items by design.

Comment: `sap.m.Select` is the correct answer!  
`sap.ui.commons.DropdownBox` is deprecated.

Answer (score 1):

@Abul: you meant enabled: false ? That works for me

I am creating an array of Comboboxes, each time i press on add-button, where i increase the counter:

```
    var oComboBox_PosA = [];
     oComboBox_PosA[COUNTER_Item] = new sap.ui.commons.ComboBox("Combo_PosA"+COUNTER_Item,{
            items : [ new sap.ui.core.ListItem({
                text : "Combo 1"
            }), new sap.ui.core.ListItem({
                text : "Combo 2"
            }) ],
            enabled: false 
        });
```

But Jan is right, one could just use a TextField/view or DropdownBox